# Does this C++ code acutally have a dangling pointer?

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer

I have class `B`, which contains a pointer for object of class `A`. I want them to share their position, so I used `std::shared_ptr` for it. Below is a short version of this code:

```cpp
struct A {
    std::shared_ptr<int> pos;

    A(const A& right, std::shared_ptr<int> _pos = nullptr) :
        pos(_pos == nullptr ? (std::make_shared<int>()) : _pos) { }
};

struct B {
    std::shared_ptr<int> pos;
    A* a;
    
    B(const B& right) :
        pos(std::make_shared<int>()), 
        a(new A(*right.a, pos)) { }
};
```

In the actual program it seems to work fine, however Visual Studio gives warning `C26815 for dangling pointer` in the `B` copy constructor, when giving value to `a`. Removing `pos` from `B` doesn't affect the warning, but if it's also removed from `A` the warning disappears, so I guess it have something to do with `shared_ptr`? Is there a dangling pointer here, or it's a false warning?

Comment: The problem is likely not with the `std::shared_ptr`, but with `a`, the normal pointer. You are not following the [Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724). (And thus have a memory leak when an object of B is destroyed, moved or copied)

Comment: Unrelated, if you use `std::make_shared<int>()` as the default value of the `_pos` parameter to `A::A` you can eliminate the terse ternary expression in its member-init list. Not sure why you settled on `nullptr`, but it isn't necessary. Just saying.

Comment: The full error message from that [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26815?view=msvc-160) is "Warning C26815 The pointer is dangling because it points at a temporary instance that was destroyed."

Comment: Please give a [mcve].